# Customizing Marketing Cloud Homepage UI to have message box pop-up when a user logs in - possible?

Tags: visualforce, marketing-cloud, javascript, home-page-component, popup-window

Is it possible to display a pop-up window or a message box, containing text and buttons to agree and disagree to the message, when a user signs into an account and loads the Marketing Cloud homepage?

The only answer I could find so far was to set up an SSO from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud (instead of MC login page) then generate a custom login flow so the users have to accept/read before login. This is due to the fact that Marketing Cloud has very limited UI freedom unlike Salesforce. I am not sure if this is correct, but it is the best solution I have so far.

Comment: I haven't seen anything close to this being a possibility in Marketing Cloud.  Their UI is pretty darn locked down.

Comment: yea, sent in a support ticket as well, and they came back saying it is not possible.